# How to put an ArrayList String's into JLabels

Tags: arraylist, jlabel

I'm having trouble figuring out how to use my ArrayList's Variable's into my JLabel's. What i'm trying to do is set each of the label's to specific string's in my Array. The order of the sentence's created by my Arraylist is det, adv, det, adv, verb, adj, noun. Basically, my program is supposed to create random sentence's with this order of words and when the JButton is clicked the program needs to randomize another sentence.

Here's what I've got

```
label.setText("word1");
    window.getContentPane().add(label); 
label2.setText("word2");    
window.getContentPane().add(label2);
JLabel label3 = new JLabel();
label3.setText("word3");
window.getContentPane().add(label3);
JLabel label4 = new JLabel();
label4.setText("word4");
window.getContentPane().add(label4);
JLabel label5 = new JLabel();   
label5.setText("word5");
window.getContentPane().add(label5);
JLabel label6 = new JLabel();
label6.setText("word6");
window.getContentPane().add(label6);
JLabel label7 = new JLabel();
label7.setText("word7");
window.getContentPane().add(label7);
JLabel label8 = new JLabel();
label8.setText("word8");
window.getContentPane().add(label8);

JButton r = new JButton();
r.setText("Random Sentence");
window.getContentPane().add(r);

ArrayList<String> adj, adv , det, noun, verb;
    adj = new ArrayList<String>();
    adv = new ArrayList<String>();
    det = new ArrayList<String>();
    noun = new ArrayList<String>();
    verb = new ArrayList<String>();
    adj.add("soft");
    adj.add("friendly");
    adj.add("fierce");
    adj.add("angry");
    adj.add("hip");
    adj.add("small");
    adj.add("large");
    adj.add("prickly");
    adj.add("mean");
    adj.add("nice");
    adj.add("quirky");
    adj.add("colorless");
    adj.add("green");
    adj.add("red");
    adj.add("blue");
    adj.add("humorless");
    adj.add("funny");
    adj.add("sad");
    adj.add("melancholy");
    adj.add("hilarious");
    adj.add("loud");
    adj.add("proud");           
    adv.add("quickly");
    adv.add("sluggishly");
    adv.add("sheepishly");
    adv.add("aggresively");
    adv.add("blandly");
    adv.add("anxiously");
    adv.add("badly");
    adv.add("boldly");
    adv.add("bravely");
    adv.add("cowardly");
    adv.add("courageously");
    adv.add("eagerly");
    adv.add("foolishly");
    adv.add("gererously");
    adv.add("innocently");
    det.add("the");
    det.add("a");
    det.add("one");
    det.add("that");
    det.add("some");
    det.add("every");
    det.add("this");
    det.add("my");
    det.add("your");
    det.add("his");
    det.add("her");
    det.add("mom's");
    det.add("dad's");
    det.add("granny's");
    det.add("grandpa's");
    det.add("auntie's");
    det.add("uncle's");
    noun.add("cat");
    noun.add("dog");
    noun.add("hamster");
    noun.add("lizard");
    noun.add("snake");
    noun.add("rabbit");
    noun.add("gerbil");
    noun.add("mouse");
    noun.add("parakeet");
    noun.add("goldfish");
    noun.add("porcupine");
    noun.add("worm");
    noun.add("slug");
    noun.add("wasp");
    noun.add("eagle");
    noun.add("sheep");
    noun.add("cow");
    noun.add("pig");
    noun.add("antelope");
    noun.add("tiger");
    noun.add("lion");
    noun.add("cheetah");
    noun.add("wolf");
    noun.add("fox");
    noun.add("hound");
    noun.add("ferret");
    verb.add("chased");
    verb.add("hit");
    verb.add("ate");
    verb.add("bit");
    verb.add("cuddled");
    verb.add("brought");
    verb.add("bought");
    verb.add("sold");
    verb.add("paid");
    verb.add("taught");
    verb.add("snuggled");
    verb.add("smacked");
    verb.add("irritated");
    verb.add("embarrassed");
    verb.add("kissed");
    verb.add("hugged");
    verb.add("decieved");
    verb.add("delayed");
    verb.add("intimidated");
    verb.add("dropped");
    verb.add("kicked");
    verb.add("froze");
    verb.add("forgave");
    verb.add("mocked");
    for (String a : adj) 
    for (String b : adv)
    for (String c : det)
    for (String d : noun)
    for (String e : verb){
    System.out.println( c +" "+ b +" "+ d +" "+ b +" "+ e +" "+ a +" "+ d);


    java.util.Collections.shuffle(adj);
    java.util.Collections.shuffle(det);
    java.util.Collections.shuffle(adv);
    java.util.Collections.shuffle(noun);
    java.util.Collections.shuffle(verb);
    LinkedList<String> shu = new java.util.LinkedList<String>();    
    java.util.Iterator<String> it;
    it = shu.iterator();
    if (it.hasNext()) { System.out.println(it.next()); }

    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int randomNumber = ...;
label.setText(adj.get(randomNumber));
label1.setText(adv.get(randomNumber));
..etc
```

If you had placed your labels and arraylists into arrays, you could do this:

```
int randomNumber = ...;
for(int i = 0; i < labelArray.length; i++){
    labelList[i].setText(wordList[i].get(randomNumber));
}
```

Comment: so using that method you say there should i reorganize where i set my adj variables to before my JLabel's?

Comment: No, I was suggesting that you place your adj, verb, etc. into an array, since it would make your life a little easier. The first solution I suggested should still work, it will just be more code.